# Finding the LMS estimator.

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, expected-value, least-squares

I was reading [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X), and the following question appears as exercise $18$ in the 8th chapter:

> Swallowed Buffon's needle. A doctor is treating a patient who has accidentally swallowed a needle. The key factor in whether to operate on the patient is the length $\Theta$ of the needle, which is unknown, but is assumed to be uniformly distributed between 0 and $l > 0$.
>
> We wish to form an estimate of $\Theta$ based on $X$, its projected length in an X-ray. We introduce a two-dimensional coordinate system and write: $$X = \Theta cosW$$
> Where $W$ is the acute angle formed by the needle and one of the axes. We assume that $W$ is uniformaly distributed in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$, and is independent from $\Theta$.
>
> (a) Find the LMS estimator $E[\Theta|X]$. in particular, derive $F_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta), f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta), f_X(x), f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|X)$, and then compute $E[\Theta|X=x]$.

My solution goes as follows:

$$F_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta) = P(X \le x | \Theta=\theta)$$
$$ \qquad \qquad = P(\Theta cosW \le x | \Theta=\theta)$$
$$ \qquad \qquad = P(\theta cosW \le x)$$
$$ \qquad \qquad = P(cosW \le x/{\theta})$$
Since $W$ is uniformly in the range $[0, \pi/2]$, then $cosW$ is uniformly in the range $[0, 1]$, so:
$$F_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta) = x/{\theta}$$
We differentiate with respect to$x$ to find that:
$$f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta) = 1/{\theta}$$

And:
$$f_X(x) = \int_x^l d\theta/{\theta} = ln(l/x)$$

Using Bayes' rule we can find that:
$$f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = \frac1{\theta} ln^{-1}(l/x)$$

And:
$$E[\Theta|X=x] = \int_x^l \theta f_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) d\theta$$
$$\qquad \qquad = \int_x^l \theta ln^{-1}(l/x) d\theta$$
$$\qquad \qquad = \frac12(l^2-x^2) ln^{-1}(l/x)$$

But the answer of the solution manual of the book is:
$$\frac{\sqrt{l^2-x^2}}{log\left( \frac{l+ \sqrt{l^2-x^2}}{x} \right)}$$

Which is quite messy, but in the end they mention that:

> It is worth noting that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}E[\Theta|X=x] =0$ and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow l}E[\Theta|X=x] = l$, as one would expect.

My solution satifies this limits, but is it correct?